# C# PropertyInfo GetValue() returns "Object does not match target type"

Tags: c#, generics, getvalue

I have a project that is reading rows returned from a SQL Server View, let's call the view 'Foo', and writing these rows to a series of files.  Using LINQ2SQL to reference the view in my project, results from  Foo are called 'FooResults'.

The method provided below accepts the type of object to parse as well as the delimiter, the path to write the file to and a generic list of the data to be parsed. I've indicated where the exception is thrown.

```
public void WriteRecords<T>(T classType, string delimiter, string outputPath, List<T> data)
{
    // Extract the property names and format as a delimited string
    var properties = classType.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
    var headerLine = string.Join(delimiter, properties.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray());
    var formattedHeaderLine = new[] { headerLine };

    // Foreach line in the data provided, extract the values and format as delimited string
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var pinfo in d.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                // This is the line causing the problems
                var value = pinfo.GetValue(pinfo, null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is:

> Object does not match target type

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var value = pinfo.GetValue(pinfo, null);
```

Should be

```
var value = pinfo.GetValue(d, null);
```

You should be passing the instance instead of the PropertInfo itself.

Comment: Funny that this is exactly what the message said. The target type did not match.